# Moments weeks In Year is not a function

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to get count week from a year using momentjs as below commend,

### Example 1: work well

```js
let now = moment("01/06/2018");
var weekresult = now.week();
alert(weekresult);
```

### Example 2:

```js
var weekinYear = now.weeksInYear();
alert(weekinYear);
```

### Example 2: Error

```
Uncaught TypeError: now.weeksInYear is not a function
```

Run at [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/118091/)

Comment: `weeksInYear` was added in version 2.6.0. You're using 2.2.1 which is almost 5 years old.

Comment: Yes, Coding forget to check version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weeks-in-year/) says, [`isoWeeksInYear()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weeks-in-year/) is available since version `2.6.0+`, while you are using moment `2.2.1` in the linked fiddle.

Moreover, since `"01/06/2018"` is neither ISO 8601 nor RFC 2822 compliant you have to use [`moment(String, String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) instead of [`moment(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).

Here a live sample with lastest version:

```js
let now = moment("01/06/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY");
var weekresult = now.week();
console.log(weekresult);
var weekinYear = now.weeksInYear();
console.log(weekinYear);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```